# Check if an object is present in a nested array reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following set of data:

## person:

```
person: { id:1
          groups:[
                  {id:1 , name: john, permissions : [{id:1 , codename="can_edit"},{id:2,codename="can_write"},{id:3,codename="can_delete"}]} ,
        
                  ]
            }
```

What i wish to do is conduct some conditional rendering based on whether this user has a permission.

```
             { this.passtest()?
            <Button type="primary" shape="circle" icon={<EditOutlined />}/>
              :
              null
              }
```

This will then call the `this.passtest()` method which will contain the logic for checking if the user has the permission i require :

```
   passtest(){
    const passing = this.props.person.groups.forEach(function(group) {
      // Not sure what logic I can put here to return true as long as the permission 'codename' field tallies 
     });

    return passing
  }
```

Would appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: What permission? What are you searching for in the `forEach` call?

Comment: the permission has a label codename which i will cross reference to. forEach call is used to iterate through all the Groups belonging to this person as there can be many

Comment: Your permissions have only ids. How do you get their label from that id? It's not part of the question and I think it might be important information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62147406/9014560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
passtest(codeName){
    return !!this.props.person.groups.find(group => group.permissions.find(permission => permission.codename === codeName));
}
```

Using:

```
{ 
  this.passtest('can_edit')?
  <Button type="primary" shape="circle" icon={<EditOutlined />}/>
  : null
}
```

For array of codeNames:

```
passtest(codeNames){
  return codeNames.every(
    codeName => !!this.props.person.groups.find(
      group => group.permissions.find(
        permission => permission.codeName === codeName
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Using:

```
{ 
  this.passtest(['can_edit', 'can_write'])?
  <Button type="primary" shape="circle" icon={<EditOutlined />}/>
  : null
}
```

Comment: Hello , one last thing if i may , is it possible to modify this so that I can throw in a list of codeNames and it has to hit every criteria in that list of codeName?

Answer (score 0):

it depends what permission you are looking for. if you're just looking for any you can do this:

```
   passtest(){
    const passing = this.props.person.groups.forEach(function(group) {
      return group.permission // this will true if permission array is > 0
     });

    return passing
  }
```

or if you're looking for something more specific

```
   passtest(){
    const passing = this.props.person.groups.forEach(function(group) {
      if  (group.permissions[0].id === 1) {
         return true
      }
      return false
     });

    return passing
  }
```

you can change this line: `if(group.permissions[0].id === 1)` to match any of the permissions you want

EDIT BELOW

if you change the permissions to be structured like this it should work:

`permissions : {codename: 'codename'}`

Comment: correct me if iim wrong , can i adapt this method to do group.permission.codename === "can_edit"

Comment: you wont be able to that unless you change `permission` to be an object

Comment: its coming from permissions , its one of the fields other than id

Comment: based on your updated code you need to do this:

`permissions[0].codename` but you can change `[0]` to be whichever one you're looking for

Comment: hey thank you so much for your help , but im still pretty confused with how would i go about checking through the entire permissions array using this method

Comment: @neowenshun have submitted a new answer. you need to look through permissions as well to achieve what you want too

Answer (score 0):

```
   passtest(){
    const passing = this.props.person.groups.forEach(function(group) {
      group.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
        // do a check in here for each permission
        if (permission.codename === 'can_edit') {
            return true
        }
      })
      return false
     });

    return passing
  }
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the help so far , however im getting an undefined when doing console.log(passing)

Comment: try using `map` instead of `forEach`